# How to simulate multiple sensors by having a 3D object render differently in different cameras

Tags: unity-game-engine, camera, rendering

I am trying to work out how to have objects render differently in different cameras.

I have a situation where we have the visible light rendering in the main camera, but the player-controlled objects may have multiple sensors, each represented by a camera.

For example, we may have:

- An IR camera which sees a light emitted by the target with a colour based upon the object's temperature, on the IR layer
- A radar, which has its own directional light, and sees only that which is the same colour as its own light on the RF layer, and would basically be a rotating vertical slit camera.
- A sound sensor, which "sees" the "light" directly emitted by the target object, as well as that reflected off other hard surfaces, on the sound layer.
- Radio direction finders, which see all colours of light on the RF layer
- An IFF/identification sensor, which sees barcodes on the body of moving objects (The ability of the 2D barcode to be read simulates shape identification with fewer processing resources than a neural network while maintaining uncertainty as to the identity of a newly-seen object until analysed)

We may also have various sensor tricks such as radar ECM, which would be simulated by having false objects placed in the field of view of the "radar camera".

The output from these sensors *may* be viewed by the players, but is *intended* to be used by player-implemented AI routines.

My scenario is 3D, but it could also be applied to 2D.

So...

What would be the best way of handling all these different cameras and renderings?  I would like to make the game objects as simple as possible, and minimise coding and CPU overhead.

Some renderings will have to change according to whatever the target object is doing - moving or firing a weapon may generate heat and sound, IFF would be complicated by cover, radar could be complicated by radar-absorbent materials, jamming, and shapes that reduce radar cross-section, and so-on.

**Edit**

These different renderings would need to be available simultaneously, as if looking at the same scene through all of the sensors, and each sensor camera would need to render appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

*edit*

Given your comment below, it appears to me that the question you intended to ask is somewhat unclear.

To answer the comment:

Set up as many camera as you need, and have each one set to "render to texture".

You will need to create a RenderTexture for each camera.

Now each camera will feed its data in real time to a texture, and you can do with those textures whatever you like.

*edit*

A simple solution to a handful of the different sensor results you're looking for is to find some shaders that produce the desired effect.

Here are some shaders you could try:

https://github.com/paganini24/ShaderExperiment

The sonic sensor I imagine would be much more difficult to create, but I think a good head start would be to explore Unity's AudioSource and AudioPlayer components. If you can get the volume/pitch of sound bring output and couple that with the position it is emitted from, you could map it to a full screen UI texture.

Not a hard solution to the sonic sensor, but hopefully that points you in the right direction.

Comment: I'm on mobile right now, so I can't see if this allows simultaneous rendering in different camera outputs of different sensor modes.  I'm not concerned so much with what the rendering looks like than having all the renderings available simultaneously.

Comment: Also... does Unity handle sound delay and attenuation over distance as well as echoes off in-game objects?  If so, I could make a custom listener, otherwise I might have to cobble together a primitive ray-tracing setup with the appropriate delays for the propagation distance.

Comment: RayTracing sounds unnecessarily heavy for the application you've outlined. If you already have the sound origin, volume and pitch, you can map it to a texture pretty easily using world to screen space transformations.

Comment: I've modified my original answer to further help regarding your comment

Comment: Does Unity have sound delay and reflection?